# Allow WebRTC webcam request using when QtWebEngine?

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, webrtc, qtwebengine

How do I allow WebRTC webcam request using when QtWebEngine (when using QML plugin or not)?

### `webengine.qml`

```
import QtQuick 2.1
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1
import QtWebEngine 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    width: 800
    height: 600
    color: "lightgray"
    visible: true
    WebEngineView {
        id: webview
        url: "https://opentokrtc.com/test"
        anchors.fill: parent
    }
}
```

On my Mac Yosemite, running the command:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/qt5/5.4.0/bin/qmlscene webengine.qml
```

but the video won't start because it's waiting for "Allow" camera

[image]

On a browser you'd have this

[image]

Is there a way to programatically set Chromium Web Engine policy e.g. [VideoCaptureAllowed](http://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#VideoCaptureAllowed)

Answer (score 3):

Add this to your WebEngineView item to grant from all origins any requested feature, or optionally limit it to specific origins and specific features:

```
    onFeaturePermissionRequested: {
        grantFeaturePermission(securityOrigin, feature, true);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need use **`QtWebEngine.experimental`** Please try this.

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtWebEngine 1.0
import QtWebEngine.experimental 1.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1
import QtQuick.Controls.Private 1.0

Window {
    visible: true
    WebEngineView {
        id: webEngineView
        url: "https://test.webrtc.org/"
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.margins: 10
        experimental.onFeaturePermissionRequested: {
            console.log("request")
            experimental.grantFeaturePermission(securityOrigin, feature, true);
        }

        readonly property string hideElementsJS: "
            function hideElement(id) {
                const el = document.getElementById(id);
                if (el) {
                    el.style.display = 'none';
                }
            }

            function hideElementsByClass(className) {
                const elList = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
                for (var i = 0, n = elList.length; i < n; ++i) {
                    elList[i].style.display = 'none';
                }
            }

            hideElement('hnArea');
            hideElement('lxSocialBarWrapper');
            hideElement('footerContent');
            hideElement('ftDisclaimers');
            hideElement('bottomNav');
            hideElement('topLinks');
            hideElement('rightMenuButtons');

            hideElementsByClass('footerText');
            hideElementsByClass('disclaimers');
        "

        onLoadingChanged: {
            if(loadRequest.status === WebEngineView.LoadSucceededStatus) {
                console.log("start")
                runJavaScript(hideElementsJS);
                console.log("stop")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

open ***fancybrowser*** project
add in mainwindow.cpp inside function MainWindow::MainWindow(const QUrl& url)

> ```
> connect(view->page(), SIGNAL(featurePermissionRequested(QUrl,QWebEnginePage::Feature)),SLOT(test(QUrl,QWebEnginePage::Feature)));
> ```

also add

> ```
> void MainWindow::test(QUrl q, QWebEnginePage::Feature f) {
>     view->page()->setFeaturePermission(q, f, 
>     QWebEnginePage::PermissionGrantedByUser); 
> }
> ```

in mainwindow.cpp and mainwindow.h below

> protected slots:
>
> ```
> void test(QUrl q, QWebEnginePage::Feature f);
> ```

then it all works!!